# Python if creates false positive result

Tags: python

I'm trying to investigate my AWS resources by listing all and checking whether they have special `troux` tag.

When iterating through my results I'm getting duplicate rows for some resources, both stating that `troux` tag does and doesn't exist at the same time.

```
import boto3
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

#if using WSL2
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='profile')

client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_stacks')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate()

result = []

for page in page_iterator:
    for stack in page['Stacks']:
        if "department_name_" in stack["StackName"]:
            for dict in stack["Tags"]:
                for key, value in dict.items():
                    if value in ("troux_id", "troux_uid"):
                        stack_with_troux = stack["StackName"] + " " + dict.get('Key') + ": " + dict.get('Value')
                        result.append(stack_with_troux)
                    else:
                        stack_without_troux = stack["StackName"] + " is missing troux tag!"
                        result.append(stack_without_troux)


print(result)
```

`for dict in stack["Tags"]:` returns following data:

```
{'Key': 'tag', 'Value': 'abc'}
{'Key': 'tag', 'Value': 'abc'}
{'Key': 'tag', 'Value': 'abc'}
{'Key': 'troux_id', 'Value': 'xyz'}
{'Key': 'tag', 'Value': 'xyz'}
{'Key': 'tag', 'Value': 'abc'}
{'Key'......
```

Final outcome is:

```
department_name_resource_one  is missing troux tag!
department_name_resource_one  is missing troux tag!
department_name_resource_one  is missing troux tag!
department_name_resource_one  is missing troux tag!
department_name_resource_one  troux_id: xyz
department_name_resource_one  is missing troux tag!
```

Expected is that loop should stop if `troux` is found else print `missing tag`

```
department_name_resource_one  is missing troux tag!
department_name_resource_two  troux_id: xyz
department_name_resource_three is missing troux tag!
```

Comment: Your dicts have two entries, and you loop over both. Add print or logging statements before the  if and you'll see that you process each dict twice. Instead of looping over the dict, check if it has a Key entry and a Value entry, then check what their values are.

Comment: This would be easier in a helper function that takes stack. It can return true immediately if it finds what you were looking for, or return False after finishing iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for key, value in dict.items():
```

Each of those dicts has **two** items.  Therefore the loop will execute twice for each dict.

For this dictionary `{'Key': 'troux_id', 'Value': 'xyz'}`, the if statement

```
if value in ("troux_id", "troux_uid"):
```

... is true for one of those loop iterations (where the value is `troux_id`), and false for the other (where the value is `xyz`).

The real problem is that you're printing "missing tag" if the **current item** doesn't match, when instead you should wait until you've seen **all** of the items in a dict, and only print that message if **none** of them matched.